# Remove webpack warnings from create-react-app project

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

Is it possible to configure webpack to not show warnings in the chrome dev console using a project that was created with create-react-app?

The warnings that I'm getting are:

```
warning  Definition for rule 'jsx-a11y/img-has-alt' was not found  jsx-a11y/img-has-alt
```

However, there are no `<img>` elements in this project.

Additionally, this is the version of create-react-app I am using:

```
"react-scripts": "^0.9.3"
```

This is my `.eslintrc`:

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "semi": [2, "never"],
    "indent": ["error", "tab"],
    "react/jsx-indent": [2, "tab"],
    "no-tabs": 0,
    "no-unexpected-multiline": 2,
    "jsx-a11y/anchor-has-content": "off",
    "react/forbid-prop-types": 0,
    "no-multi-spaces": ["error", { exceptions: { "VariableDeclarator": true, "Property": true } }],
    "react/jsx-indent-props": [2, 'tab'],
    "no-console": 0
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are those warnings and what versions of the tools you mentioned are you using?

Comment: @virzen just added the version info to the question. thx.

Comment: To reconfigure anything in create-react-app you need to eject.

Comment: Have you touch eslint config in any way?

Comment: @virzen i just added my eslintrc to the original question. thx!

Comment: And have you installed https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y?

Comment: It's one of the peer dependencies of the airbnb config. https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb#eslint-config-airbnb-1

Comment: yes, i installed the airbnb config with the command from the docs: export PKG=eslint-config-airbnb;
  npm info "$PKG@latest" peerDependencies --json | command sed 's/[\{\},]//g ; s/: /@/g' | xargs npm install --save-dev "$PKG@latest"
)

Comment: Ok. Have you ejected the configuration before adding eslint config?

Comment: No, I didn't eject from create-react-app ... Would ideally like to not do that, and get rid of these jsx-a11y errs as well ...

Comment: Ok, I suspect this is caused by this breaking change in jsx-a11y: https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/commit/24b6193318baf36bb0a9d99b6135a6909f55cd3b. You might have outdated version of airbnb, but the latest one of jsx-a11y and it tries to use rule that no longer exists. Have you tried to update `react-scripts`?

Comment: Yep, there was a bump of jsx-a11y package in version 9.4 of create-react-app https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/releases/tag/v0.9.4

Comment: hiya! ok ... so i upgraded to 9.4 and the error still persisted @WiktorCzajkowski i then upgraded to 9.5 and it also still persisted. i even then removed and then re-added the airbnb eslint and the problem still persists.